# RoR How to do more than one Build association in the same block without loosing information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I'm just starting now a small project so I can learn more of the new possibilities in RoR 3 . So I was reading about associations between objects, more specific the "build" method. Mu problem is when I use it one time no problem like:

```
@note = product.notes.build(:product => product)
```

and then I change some attributes of note and no problem.

The problem is note `belongs_to` two objects `Product` and `User` so when I'm creating an object I need to build that association so I need to do something like

```
@note = product.notes.build(:product => product)
@note = user.notes.build(:user => user)
```

After the second build I've lost the association with Product because the "build" method will return a new instance.

Am I missing something of the way I should build the associations ? Should I do it another way ?

Thanks !

```
# POST /notes
# POST /notes.xml
def create
  user = current_user
  product = Product.find(2)
  @note = product.notes.build(:product => product)
  @note = user.notes.build(:user => user)

  @note.rating = params[:note][:rating]
  @note.text = params[:note][:text]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @note.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@note, :notice => 'Note was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @note, :status => :created, :location => @note }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @note.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Here goes the definition of Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  has_many :notes ,:dependent => :destroy
end
```

and Note

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the way you prefer:

- `@note = Note.new(:user => user, :product => product)`
- `@note = product.notes.build(:user => user)`
- `@note = user.notes.build(:product => product)`

If you write two `@note =`, you reassign another object to `@note` and the first one is lost.

You can also write something like this:

```
@note = product.notes.build
@note.user = user
```